# Show the sum of probabilities is less than or equal to twice the probability of the union

Tags: probability, summation, independence

I can't solve this problem out of my class's textbook although it seemingly is very simple. Could someone solve this or point me in the correct direction please?

$Let(Ω,F,P)$ be a probability space and let $E_1,...,E_n ∈ F$ be mutually independent events. If $P(⋃^{n}_{i=1}E_i)≤1/2$, then

$$∑^{n}_{i=1}P(E_i)≤2P(⋃^{n}_{i=1}E_i)$$

This would be trivial if they were disjoint events, but unsure how to show this if they're only independent, although I can tell this is likely easy and I'm missing something terribly obvious.

My first thought was to use inclusion/exclusion but i cant get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily proved by induction on $n$. For $n=2$ we have $P(E_1)+P(E_2)\leq P(E_1 \cup E_2)+P(E_1 \cup E_2)=2P(E_1 \cup E_2)$.

Suppose that result is true for $n$ independent events and consider $n+1$ independent events: $E_1,E_2,...,E_{n+1}$. We have $$ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} P(E_i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(E_i)+P(E_{n+1})$$ $$\leq P(\bigcup_{i \leq n} E_i)+P(E_{n+1})\leq 2P(\bigcup_{i \leq {n}} E_i)+P( E_{n+1}) \leq 2P(\bigcup_{i \leq {n+1}} E_i)$$ The last step follows from the folowing :

If $A$ and $B$ are independent and $P(A\cup B) \leq \frac 1  2$ then  $2P(A)+P(B) \leq 2P(A\cup B)$.  [Use the fact that $P(A\cup  B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$].

Comment: This is clearly it. I was driving myself insane trying to factor in independence somehow.

Comment: @bof Thanks for the comment. The original proof was wrong, but induction does work. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Ralph Actutally inclusion exclusion for two indepdent events is required. There was  a mistake in my answer and I haev corrected it.

Comment: Oh I see now, I decided to sleep on it before I came back to the problem, I didn't see your error at first but its clear looking at the edits. Thank you!